# Spring jpa database connection for native query

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring application that have to connect to a sql server db. There are no @Entity class and there ate no @Repository because the tables and the columns of the tables are unknown to the application. I have created a class and used an entity manager to execute queries, but I'm not sure this is the best choice in this case:

```
@Service
public class MyRepo {
private final EntityManager entityManager;

public MyRepo(@Qualifier("myEntityManagerFactory") EntityManager _entityManager){
    entityManager = _entityManager;
}

public void execQuery(){
    String queryStr = "select TOP (10) * from [MyTable]";
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryStr);
    List<Object> queryRes = query.getResultList();
}
```

}

My question is if it is more correct, in my scenario, to create a "classic" connection to the db instead of create an entity manager (since there are no entities); 
something like:

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("connection string","user","password");
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select TOP (10) * from [MyTable]");
```

Thanks a lot for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing JPA just to hold the connection.

You should go for `JdbcTemplate` instead.

Don't use the starter for Spring Data JPA, instead use the `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` (Not Spring *Data* JDBC).
Get a `JdbcTemplate` or a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` injected and use them to execute your SQL code.